# Extjs 4 and cakephp 1.3 model integration

Tags: cakephp-1.3, extjs4

this is maintainrecord.js which placed cake webroot js directory and also extjs 4 folder also placed in same directory.i access extjs 4 through this js file

code:maintainrecord.js

```
function getBaseURL() {
         var url = location.href;  
         window.location.href;
         var baseURL = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('/', 14));
if (baseURL.indexOf('http://localhost') != -1) {
    var url = location.href;  
    var pathname = location.pathname;  
    var index1 = url.indexOf(pathname);
    var index2 = url.indexOf("/", index1 + 1);
    var baseLocalUrl = url.substr(0, index2);
    return baseLocalUrl + "/";
}
else {
    return baseURL + "/";
}
  }
 var pathname=location.pathname;
 var myarray = pathname.split("/");
 window.id=myarray[4];
 Ext.onReady(function(){
var r=getBaseURL();
// Define our data model
Ext.define('Employee', {
                        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
                        fields: [
                                'id',
                                'notes',
                                'asset_id',
                                'date_',
                                'maint_picture',
                                'maint_condition1',
                                'maint_condition2',
                                'maint_condition3',
                                'maint_condition4'
                                ]
                    }
            );  
            //alert('th correct');
//cake php crud and create the Data Store

        var store = new Ext.data.Store
            ({

                 proxy: {
                            type: 'ajax',
                            api: {
                                    create:  { url: r+'toolbar2/tbl_maintenance_records/create',  method: 'POST' },
                                      read:  { url: r+'toolbar2/tbl_maintenance_records/index?id='+window.id,    method: 'GET'},
                                    update:  { url: r+'toolbar2/tbl_maintenance_records/update',  method: 'POST' },
                                   destroy:  { url: r+'toolbar2/tbl_maintenance_records/delete',  method: 'POST' }
                                 },
                         reader: {
                                      type: 'json', // We expect the server to give us a JSON string as a response
                                      root: 'users'
                                  }
                        },
              autoLoad: true,
              autoSave: false,
             listeners: {
                          exception: function(proxy, type, action, o, result, records) 
                              {
                                if (type = 'remote') 
                                    {
                                      Ext.Msg.alert("Could not " + action, result.raw.message);
                                    }
                                else if (type = 'response') 
                                    {
                                      Ext.Msg.alert("Could not " + action, "Server's response could not be decoded");
                                    } 
                                else 
                                    {
                                      Ext.Msg.alert("Store sync failed", "Unknown error");
                                    }
                                }
                        }
            });
        //alert('crud correct');

 function syncStore(rowEditing, changes, r, rowIndex) {
        store.save();
    }
//create drop down elements
     var cond1 = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
            fields: ['maint_condition1'], data : [['Excellent'],['Poor'],['New'],['good'],['scrap']]});

     var cond2 = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
            fields: ['maint_condition2'], data : [['Excellent'],['Poor'],['New']]});

     var cond3 = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
            fields: ['maint_condition3'], data : [['New'],['Excellent']]});

     var cond4 = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
            fields: ['maint_condition4'], data : [['New'],['Excellent'],['good'],['Poor'],['scrap']]});
//ready store
    //var cb_select2 =new Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel();
    var asset_edit = new Ext.form.TextField();
    var notes_edit = new Ext.form.TextField();
    var date_edit = new Ext.form.DateField({format: 'm/d/Y'});
    var rowEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
    clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
    autoCancel: false,
    saveText: 'Save',
    listeners: {
                afteredit: syncStore
               }
    });
    var cond1_edit = new Ext.form.DateField({format: 'combo'});
    //var sm = Ext.grid.getSelectionModel();  
//alert('before grid');
//Grid for show data
    var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    id:'grid1',
    renderTo: document.body,
    extend: 'Ext.form.ComboBox',
    plugins:[rowEditing],
    frame: true,
    height:140,
    width:950,
    enableColumnMove: false,
    store: store,
    columns: [
                {header: "Asset ID", dataIndex: 'asset_id'},
                {header: "Maint. ID", dataIndex: 'id'},
                {header: "Date", dataIndex: 'date_',editor:date_edit},
                {header: "Notes", dataIndex: 'notes',editor: notes_edit},
                {header: "Maint_condition1", dataIndex: 'maint_condition1', sortable: true,width: 120,
                          editor: new Ext.form.ComboBox({
                                                         allowBlank: false,
                                                         mode: 'local',
                                                         store: cond1,
                                                         valueField: 'maint_condition1',
                                                         displayField: 'maint_condition1',
                                                         triggerAction: 'all',
                                                         editable: false
                                                         }
                                                        )},
                {header: "Maint_condition2", dataIndex: 'maint_condition2', sortable: true,width: 120,
                          editor: new Ext.form.ComboBox({
                                                         allowBlank: false,
                                                         mode: 'local',
                                                         store: cond2,
                                                         valueField: 'maint_condition2',
                                                         displayField: 'maint_condition2',
                                                         triggerAction: 'all',
                                                         editable: false
                                                         }
                                                        )},
                {header: "Maint_condition3", dataIndex: 'maint_condition3', sortable: true,width: 120,
                         editor: new Ext.form.ComboBox({
                                                        allowBlank: false,
                                                        mode: 'local',
                                                        store: cond3,
                                                        valueField: 'maint_condition3',
                                                        displayField: 'maint_condition3',
                                                        triggerAction: 'all',
                                                        editable: false
                                                        }
                                                      )},
                {header: "Maint_condition4", dataIndex: 'maint_condition4', sortable: true,width: 120,
                         editor: new Ext.form.ComboBox({
                                                         allowBlank: false,
                                                         mode: 'local',
                                                         store: cond4,
                                                         valueField: 'maint_condition4',
                                                         displayField: 'maint_condition4',
                                                         triggerAction: 'all',
                                                         editable: false
                                                        }
                                                      )}
                ],

          tbar: [{
            text: 'Add Record',
            icon: 'http://localhost/toolbar2/app/webroot/images/table_add.png',
            cls: 'x-btn-text-icon',
            handler: function() {
            grid.getStore().insert(0, new Employee({
                    id: 0,
                    notes: 'New Notes',
                    asset_id: window.id,            
                    //maint_condition3: false

           }));

                rowEditing.startEdit(0,0);
            }
         },{
           text: 'Remove Record',
           icon: 'http://localhost/toolbar2/app/webroot/images/table_delete.png',
            cls: 'x-btn-text-icon',
            handler: function() {
                var sm = grid.getSelectionModel();
                rowEditing.cancelEdit();
                store.remove(sm.getSelection());
                if (store.getCount() > 0) 
                {
                 sm.select(0);
                }

             }
           }]

     });
           //alert('after grid');

          //alert('gffgf');
     //alert(r);
           });
```

add and delete of this application its not working help me to solve my problem,.....

Answer (score 0):

A single `=` is an assignment, not a comparison for use in an `if` statement. You want either `==` or `===`. To understand the difference [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use).

In your reader you have `, Employee`, that makes no sense, I'd guess it's meant to be inside the curly brace for `model: 'Employee'`.

Fix those issues first.

Comment: thanx for your reply I just want to know how to access cakephp model from extjs 4.In extjs 3 i use api code :   api:{
  create:  { url: r+'toolbar2/tbl_maintenance_records/create'},
  update:  { url: r+'toolbar2/tbl_maintenance_records/update'},
  read:{url:r+'toolbar2/tbl_maintenance_records/index?id='+window.id},
        destroy: { url: r+'toolbar2/tbl_maintenance_records/delete' }
  
 }

Comment: `api` is not a config variable that you can set on a store. Quick search on the internet indicates you need add this under the `proxy` config variable. [Store documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-proxy)

Comment: thanks.I solve this problem but this time occurs "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getProxy' of undefined" due to store(store: store) if i comment this line then grid appears in cakephp view but data not occurs.and when i click on add button then  show "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'xtype' of undefined"  i put my change code in my question code.help to solve it. thanx

Comment: You've defined `Ext.data.HttpProxy`, and I cannot see this in the documentation anywhere - where has that come from? I said you needed to set the `proxy` config on the store. You're getting an error as you're trying to assign one thing to another with an unmatched datatype. `Ext.data.HttpProxy` != `Ext.data.Store`.

Comment: thanks i change my code but it shows error on add time and normaly its show "ext-all-debug.js:5299Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'indexOf'" error please see my changed code.thanks

Comment: Your model is lacking any data types. It cannot do any inserts without that. I **strongly** suggest you go back to the documentation and check that you're setting up all the Ext components correctly.